# How to convert outdated MySQL `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY column1` query to correct MySQL 8 syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, distinct

I am trying to convert old 5.6 MySQL queries to be compatible with MySQL 8. Unfortunately many of the queries contain joins with `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY column1`. These cause a syntax error in the latest version of mysql. I have tried several variations of group by and distinct to try and achieve the same behavior but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you share one of the failing querys, along with the **exact** error message?

Comment: If `column1` is the primary key, it should still work.

Comment: And if it wasn't the primary key, you probably weren't getting the expected results in the old version -- it won't get all columns from the same row in the group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1 order by column1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This does return one extra column, but is otherwise equivalent.

If your tables have a primary key, say `id`, then you can also do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.column1 = t.column1
             );
```

Note:  Some folks wrote code such as yours under the assumption that MySQL would return the *first* row for each `column1` value.  That is a grave misunderstanding of SQL, because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets so "first" is not even defined.  MySQL documentation also cautions against making such an assumption.

Comment: The second solution worked great for my use case. Thanks Gordon!